# Why did my middle mouse button stop working in firefox exclusively?

Tags: firefox, mouse, touchpad

For some reason I'm plagued by especially rare bugs. This time my middle mouse button ceased to work in **firefox** exclusively. I can use it to copy stuff in terminal or to start another instance of a program clicking on the program's icon on the unity launcher bar.

But I **can't use my middle mouse button to open a link in a new tab**. That's quite annoying. The button click gets recognized, as the links highlight as I middle click them. A new tab just isn't opened.

I already disabled all addons to firefox to see if it's an addon problem. Turns out it's not. **Even purging firefox and reinstalling didn't help**.

I own a **Logitec MX510** mouse on my **HP laptop that also has Synaptics TouchPad**. On the touchpad the middle and left button never worked in ubuntu at all (firefox or anywhare else).

Any ideas what could be wrong? What else could I try.

**Edit**:
Now the problem has reached my work PC as well. After the latest firefox-update (to version 6.0.2): The right mouse button on my work PC (Desktop) does open the context menu, but as soon as I move my mouse even the tiniest bit, the menu closes. So the **problems might be related to the 6.0.2 update of firefox** or not, but it's certainly suspicious that both PC have mouse problems ins firefox only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Purging Firefox removes global settings only, not the Firefox profile itself. To check whether it's an issue related to your Firefox profile settings, try creating a new, clean one:

```
mkdir /tmp/firefox-test
firefox -profile /tmp/firefox-test -no-remote &
```

`/tmp/firefox-test` can be removed afterwards. If the problem is persistent, you might want to take a look at your settings in the `about:config` URL, search for keywords like "mouse", "click" and "tab". Otherwise, you could check the `prefs.js` file in your Firefox profile folder which is located at `~/.mozilla/firefox/XXXXXXX.PROFILENAME/prefs.js`. If you can't get any out of it, quit the Firefox instance using this profile folder and rename / remove this prefs.js file to **reset** your settings. If this still does not help, export data like your bookmarks and create a new profile using the Profile Manager which can be started with `firefox -p`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the fix:

1. Install `gpointing-device-settings`

   ```
   sudo apt-get install gpointing-device-settings
   ```
2. Then run

   ```
   gpointing-device-settings
   ```

   Click the genius optical mouse option, and check the 'use middle button emulation'

Comment: Not sure why it worked, but it did. Note: Need to restart any app to start accepting middle mouse button input again.

Answer (score -1):

go to 0.9.11 (update to the current 0.9.10, fixing the tabmixplus - greasemonkey snafu of 0.9.10 -- strangely I stumbled upon this error only with todays firefox 7 update from the ppa...)

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/versions/?page=1#version-0.9.11

Comment: The OP writes that the problem remains with addons disabled.

Answer (score -2):

solution is here:
https://superuser.com/questions/332782/middle-click-tab-opening-stopped-working-in-firefox/332794#332794

I simply uninstalled Greasemonkey, which I did not use anyway.

Comment: The OP writes that the problem remains with addons disabled.